# Unable to find a model that matches key is shown when spring-boot app is started

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a spring-boot application with swagger and OpenAPI. Before adding OpenApi the error didn't show, so I assume it must be connected to it. This is the error showing in the logs

```
[ERROR] Unable to find a model that matches key ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='com.myproject.repository.model', name='ErrorJson'}, viewDiscriminator=null, validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}
```

This is my bean for the swagger

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host(hostname)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.myproject.repository"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
    }
```

If any other information is needed I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue by adding this property

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3: false
```

Springfox 3.0 uses v3 models by default, but `source.getResponses()` gives wrong type. To workaround it for now, add: `springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false` in your application.properties.